# Se mueve un Label en mi calculadora

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Estoy haciendo una calculadora en Tkinter, Python y se me mueve el Label donde se muestra la concatenación de los números, es la variable show_num. Estuve intentando solucionarlo durante un buen rato y no logro encontrar la manera.

Al intentar hacer una publicación por que me dice que estoy poniendo puro código en la publicación si es una pagina que a mi parecer es para esto.

```
import tkinter as tk

icon_path = r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Agustin\Programacion\Python-Practica\Proyectos\TkinterTutorial\Iconos\calculadora.ico'

root = tk.Tk()
icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=icon_path)
root.title("Calculator")
root.geometry("328x454")
root.iconphoto(True, icon)

def one():
    global current_num
    current_num = current_num * 10 + 1
    update_display()
    
def two():
    global current_num
    current_num = current_num * 10 + 2
    update_display()

def three():
    global current_num
    current_num = current_num * 10 +3
    update_display()

def four():
    global current_num
    current_num = current_num * 10 + 4
    update_display()

def five():
    global current_num
    current_num = current_num * 10 + 5
    update_display()

def six():
    global current_num
    current_num = current_num * 10 + 6
    update_display()

def seven():
    global current_num
    current_num = current_num * 10 + 7
    update_display()

def eight():
    global current_num
    current_num = current_num * 10 + 8
    update_display()

def nine():
    global current_num
    current_num = current_num * 10 + 9
    update_display()

def zero():
    global current_num
    current_num = current_num * 10 + 0
    update_display()

def sub():
    pass

def multiply():
    pass

def divide():
    pass

def equal():
    pass

def update_display():
    show_num.config(text=str(current_num))

current_num = 0

show_num = tk.Label(root, text=f"0",font=("Helvatica",20))
show_num.grid(column=4,row=0,padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

buttonOne = tk.Button(root, text="1",font=0.5,width=8,height=5,command=one)
buttonOne.grid(column=1,row=1)

buttonTwo = tk.Button(root, text="2",font=0.5,width=8,height=5,command=two)
buttonTwo.grid(column=2,row=1)

buttonThree = tk.Button(root, text="3",font=0.5,width=8,height=5,command=three)
buttonThree.grid(column=3,row=1)

buttonFour = tk.Button(root, text="4",font=0.5,width=8,height=5,command=four)
buttonFour.grid(column=1,row=2)

buttonFive = tk.Button(root, text="5",font=0.5,width=8,height=5,command=five)
buttonFive.grid(column=2,row=2)

buttonSix = tk.Button(root, text="6",font=0.5,width=8,height=5,command=six)
buttonSix.grid(column=3,row=2)

buttonSeven = tk.Button(root, text="7",font=0.5,width=8,height=5,command=seven)
buttonSeven.grid(column=1,row=3)

buttonEight = tk.Button(root, text="8",font=0.5,width=8,height=5,command=eight)
buttonEight.grid(column=2,row=3)

buttonNine = tk.Button(root, text="9",font=0.5,width=8,height=5,command=nine)
buttonNine.grid(column=3,row=3)

ButtonZero = tk.Button(root, text="0",font=0.5,width=8,height=5,command=zero)
ButtonZero.grid(column=1,row=4)

ButtonEqual = tk.Button(root, text="+",font=0.5,width=8,height=5)
ButtonEqual.grid(column=4,row=1)

ButtonAdd = tk.Button(root, text="-",font=0.5,width=8,height=5)
ButtonAdd.grid(column=4,row=2)

ButtonSub = tk.Button(root, text="=",font=0.5,width=8,height=5)
ButtonSub.grid(column=4,row=3)

ButtonMultiply = tk.Button(root, text="x",font=0.5,width=8,height=5)
ButtonMultiply.grid(column=2,row=4)

ButtonSplit = tk.Button(root, text="/",font=0.5,width=8,height=5)
ButtonSplit.grid(column=3,row=4)

ButtonClear = tk.Button(root, text="C",font=0.5,width=8,height=5)
ButtonClear.grid(column=4,row=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Diría que el sistema te previene de publicar una proporción incorrecta entre código y texto, por una razón, y es que difícilmente una persona en capacidad de ayudarte lea cientos de líneas de código para encontrar un problema que probablemente está mal descrito. Recomendaría que trates de explicar más a detalle lo que ocurre y reducir el código a un [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Intenta está etiqueta o algo por el estilo

```
show_num.config(anchor="e")  # Para alinear el texto a la derecha
```

Answer (score 0):

también puedes probar a realizar esto:

```
variable_x.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=3,sticky="w")
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe qué hace este código. Recuerda además que las respuestas deben ser _completas_ a la pregunta, no respuestas de "tanteo" (_prueba esto, prueba aquello_). Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.